# Need help on Springel model for galaxy simulation

Tags: galaxy, dark-matter, galactic-dynamics, disk

I am working on a code for galactic dynamics simulation. Initial conditions (positions and velocities) are based on a model with a massive dark halo and a thin exponential disk.

Now, from the following paper ["Tidal tails in CDM cosmologies"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9807320.pdf), I am studying the response of the dark matter profile.

Here's a capture of the article part that confuses me :

[image: Response of dark matter profile]

Firstly, I don't understand how one gets equation (16) from the fact that angular momentum of individual dark matter orbits is
conserved, i.e :

\begin{equation}
r_{i}\,M(r_{i})=r_{f}\,M_{f}(r_{f})\quad\quad\text{(eq 16)}       
\end{equation}

" where $r_{i}$ and $r_{f}$ are the initial and final radii of some dark matter mass shell, $M(r)$ gives the initial NFW mass
profile, and $M_{f}(r)$ is the final cumulative mass profile after the disk is formed."

**Question 1) Is (equation 16) got by the momentum theorem ? ($\dfrac{\text{d}\vec{L}}{\text{d}t} = \vec{OM} \times \vec{F}$)**

**And how to prove it, i.e what's the demonstration to get (equation 16) ?**

I don't understand what's the difference between $M(r)$ and $M_{f}(r)$.

After, it is said that $M_{f}(r)$ is the sum of the cumulative mass of the disk and the dark mass inside the initial radius
and author writes (**equation 17 on paper**) :

\begin{equation}
M_{f}\,(r_{f})=M_{d}\,(r_{f})+(1 - m_{d})\,M(r_{i})\quad\quad\text{(eq 17)}
\end{equation}

I would like to connect this equation with the total mass of galaxy which could be written (according to me) as :

\begin{equation}
M_{total}\,(r) = M_{d}\,(r) + M_{DM}\,(r) = m_{d}\, M_{DM}\,(r) + M_{DM}\,(r) = (1+m_d)\, M_{DM}\,(r)
\end{equation}

with $m_{d}$ the ratio between disk mass and halo mass.

**Question 2) Could you help me to connect the total mass with this equation (17) ?**

After with equation (18), author of paper writes that the final profile $M_{h}(r)$ of the dark matter halo is then given by :

\begin{equation}
M_{h}\,(r) = M_{f}\,(r) - M_{d}\,(r)
\end{equation}

**Question 3) So should I conclude that $M_{f}\,(r)$ is the total mass of galaxy (disk + halo) as a function of $r$ ?**

Any help would be great,

Regards

**UPDATE 1 :**

I have contacted the author of paper ["Tidal tails in CDM cosmologies"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9807320.pdf), i.e Volker Springel and here are its comments :

> Question 1*) Answer: For simplicity, you can consider that all particles are on circular
>   orbits. The initial circular velocity of a particle is $$v_i = \sqrt{(G M(r_i)/r_i)}$$, the final one is $$v_f = \sqrt{(G M(r_f)/r_f)}$$. The
>   corresponding angular momenta are $$L_i = m r_i v_i$$ and $$L_f = m r_f v_f$$.
>   Now, the angular momentum is an adiabatic invariant when the halo is
>   slowly compressed, hence $$L_i = L_f$$. The latter equation then gives eqn
>   (16) when one plugs in the velocities.
>
> Question 2*) "I don't understand what's the difference between $M(r)$ and
>   $M_f(r)$ ?"
>
> Answer:
>
> $M_i(r)$ is the initial and $M_f(r)$ the final cumulative mass profile.
>
> Question 3*)
>
> I would like to connect this equation with the total mass of galaxy which could be written as :
>
> $$ M_{total}(r) = M_d(r) + M_DM(r) = m_d M_DM(r) + M_DM(r) = (1+m_d) M_DM(r)$$
>
> Answer : This can only be written for the initial distribution in
>   this form, where the assumption is that the mass that will later make
>   up the disk is distributed proportionally to the dark matter.
>
> Question 4*)
>   Could you help me to connect the total mass with this equation (17) ?
>
> After with equation (18), you write that the final profile M_{h}(r)$ of the dark matter halo is then given by :
>
> $$M_h (r) = M_f(r) - M_d(r)$$.
>
> So should I conclude that M_f(r) is the total mass of galaxy (disk + halo) as a function of r ?
>   < Answer : "Yes."

In conclusion, I can solve my question 1*) but not question 2*) nor question 3*)

Right now, my goal is to demonstrate how to get  :

$$\begin{equation}
M_{f}\,(r_{f})=M_{d}\,(r_{f})+(1 - m_{d})\,M(r_{i})\quad\quad\text{(eq 17)}
\end{equation}$$

Any help to acheive this is welcome, thanks

Comment: Yes, that is simply the angular momentum of the shell written down, and using the fact that it's conserved.

Comment: To prove it, should I write : $$\vec{L} = \vec{constant} = $$ $$\vec{OM} \times \vec{p} = M(r_{i})r_{i}^{2}\dot{\theta}=M(r_{f})r_{f}^{2}\dot{\theta}$$ ?? But how to introduce the two different masses $M_{f}(r)$ or $M(r)$ ? If you could detail the demo. thanks a lot

Comment: I'm unsure what you're confused about. You already wrote the identity down with two different masses. $M(r_i)$ will in general be different from $M(r_f)$. And if you then call $M(r_f) = M_f$ is just a matter of notation.

Comment: $M(r)$ is called "the initial NFW mass profile" and $M_{f}(r)$ is called  is "the final cumulative mass profile after the disk is formed". Do you think that solution could be found by putting notation $M(r_f) = M_f$ ??

Comment: Given the relation above of $\vec{L}$, I can't find **equation 16**. But if I put circular velocities like $v_i = \sqrt{(G M(r_i)/r_i)}$ and $v_f = \sqrt{(G M(r_f)/r_f)}$, then I think I have to set : $\vec{L_i}=\vec{L_f}$, don't I ?

Comment: It's hard to understand the wider picture with just a snippet of your source, but it looks to me like you're trying too hard here. Angular momentum is $L=Mvr$ and angular momentum conservation is just $M_1v_1r_1 = M_2v_2r_2$. If you can say that $v_1=v_2$ (it's unclear to me if that is the case from your snippet) then you're left with $M_1r_1 = M_2r_2$.

Comment: I think it is combining centripetal acceleration (because equations and abstract "compare circular velocities to escape speed") for a low eccentricity orbit $m v^2 /r$ and center of mass for equations 16 and 17. Just a guess though.